# NodeJS server and client on Cpanel Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, cpanel

I have made a functional nodejs application that acts as a websocket server and serves a simple client webpage. I have the websocket at port 8080, and the client connects too from wss://192.168.3.101:8080. This works locally. But when I transfer this over to a Cpanel nodejs webapp on my personal domain it doesn't connect.

I understand that 192.168.3.101:8080 is only on my ip address. What address should I try connecting the client script to?

Comment: Have you tried wss://yourdomain.com:8080 ? Have you checked logs, to see if the application is running on port 8080 successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt you need a WebSocket server to serve a client webpage. But I don't know all the details, so here's a generic solution.

Ideally, you would use a global configuration (most common and simplest way is to use an environment variable) to set the hostname of your application.

On your local network, the hostname is `192.168.3.101`, but on cPanel it will be a different public IP, or ideally a domain. I recommend using a domain since IP addresses tend to change when the "machine" is rebooted.

What I would do, is setup a reverse proxy with nginx and configure a virtual host to serve WebSocket requests. The following link is a good resource that will explain step by step what to do: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/